# Register package in pojo codec provider using quarkus and panache

Tags: mongodb, quarkus-panache

I have the problem discribed [here](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-mongodb/issues/10) and therefore need to register the package containing my model in the PojoCodecProvider. I tried something like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class AppLifecycleBean {
    fun onStart(@Observes ev: StartupEvent) {
        MongoClientSettings.builder().codecRegistry(
            CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(
                MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                fromProviders(
                    PojoCodecProvider.builder()
                        .register("src/main/java/model").automatic(true).build()
                )
            )
        ).build()
    }
}
```

but with no success. Probably because I do not use the codec registery afterwards. But I dont know how I could pass this to my panache repository:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class EntityRepository : ReactivePanacheMongoRepository<Entity> {

}
```

Is it possible to inject the new configuration into panache or would I need to instantiate my own mongo client with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

So I still was not able to register those classes (and would still be happy to understand how it is done). But I found out that the discriminators work also when red without writing before, if I use the class names as discriminators, not the full qualified names as it is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this problem for the last 4 days, and now I have realized how it works.

Quakus searches for all CodecProvider and PropertyCodecProvider implementations in build time.

To do this, it uses a tool from a lib of JBoss that captures all actual implementations of a target(abstract class or interface).
[MongoClientProcessor.collectCodecProviders()](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/5a2347f0671acdc3e33fd0988588ffa7c27f9840/extensions/mongodb-client/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/mongodb/deployment/MongoClientProcessor.java#LL113C10-L113C10)

So all you have to do is implement your Codec and a CodecProvider for it...

For example:

In my case, I have to save BigDecimal as String because that's how spring does, and now I have another application in Quarkus that deal with the same collection, so what I did was:

```
public class CustomBigDecimalCodec implements Codec<BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public void encode(final BsonWriter writer, final BigDecimal value, final EncoderContext encoderContext) {
        writer.writeString(value.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal decode(final BsonReader reader, final DecoderContext decoderContext) {
        return new BigDecimal(reader.readString());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<BigDecimal> getEncoderClass() {
        return BigDecimal.class;
    }
}
```

And its Provider:

```
public class CustomCodecProvider implements CodecProvider {
    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Codec<T> get(Class<T> clazz, CodecRegistry registry) {
        if(BigDecimal.class.equals(clazz))
            return (Codec<T>) new CustomBigDecimalCodec();
        return null;
    }
}
```

In your case I'd try:

```
public class CustomCodecProvider implements CodecProvider {
    private static final PojoCodecProvider PROVIDER;

    static {
        PROVIDER = PojoCodecProvider.builder().register("src/main/java/model").automatic(true).build();
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Codec<T> get(Class<T> clazz, CodecRegistry registry) {
        return PROVIDER.get(clazz, registry);
    }
}
```

After that Quarkus will already find your CodecProvider and, it will be placed among the builtin  ones, for some reason(I couldn't find)
the custom Provider is prioritized and will return the desired codec before the builtin ones